# Hide some columns on mobile with Blazorise DataGrid

Tags: c#, user-interface, datagrid, blazor-server-side, blazorise

What is a proper syntax for hiding certain columns on small screens?

I tried using:

```
HeaderCellClass="d-none d-sm-block"
CellClass="@((_) => "d-none d-sm-block")"
```

which seemed to work BUT it resutled in some buggy UI
[image]

as you can see, columns Ident and Main Author have some kind of "ghost border line"

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this using a combination of the [BlazorSize library](https://github.com/EdCharbeneau/BlazorSize) and the Blazorise `Displayable` column attribute:

```
<DataGridColumn TItem="Year" Field="@nameof(Year.YearDesc)" Displayable="@IsMediumUpMedia" Caption="Year"></DataGridColumn>
```

Where 'IsMediumUpMedia' is one of the variables available that is true on medium or higher view ports.

Comment: I tried to use the library, I followed the setup at https://github.com/EdCharbeneau/BlazorSize, but I am hitting Cannot provide a value for property 'MqService' on type 'BlazorPro.BlazorSize.MediaQueryList'. There is no registered service of type 'BlazorPro.BlazorSize.IMediaQueryService'.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead `"d-sm-block"` -> `"d-sm-table-cell"`